# How to change change Navbar from Register/Login values to Logout Value when user Successfully sign in?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, local-storage, token, navbar

Hello Im trying to nagivagate my navbar in case User not login show specific content on navbar and in case he is log in to show other content on nav bar.
Following code is on my Nav.vue

```
<router-link  v-if="!flag" to="/login" class="btn" >Login</router-link>
        <router-link  v-if="!flag" to="/register" class="btn">Register</router-link>
        <router-link  v-if="flag" to="/logout" class="btn">Logout</router-link>
        <router-link  v-if="flag" to="/profile" class="btn">Profile</router-link>
     
    </v-app-bar>
    <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import { useStore } from "vuex"
export default {
  
    name: "app-app",
    setup() {
      const store= useStore()
      let flag = false;
      const check = () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        
          store.dispatch('setFlag',true)
        } else {
          store.dispatch('setFlag',false)
        }
      };
      check();
      return {
        flag,
        check,
```

and in my Store I have the following code:

```
import {createStore , ActionContext} from 'vuex'


export default createStore({

    state:{
        flag:false

    },
    mutations:{

        setFlag(state: { flag:boolean } , flag: boolean)   {
            state.flag= flag;

        }
    },
    actions : {

        setFlag (context: ActionContext<any, any>, flag:boolean){
            context.commit('setFlag',flag)
        }
    },
    modules : {}
})
```

When I run the app I have the following issue that I cant manage out:
Nav.vue?6cee:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')

Any ideas?

I tried the above but the error came out

Comment: Are you passing the store when you initiate vue? ie when you use `new Vue({...}, store)`

Comment: no where i can do that?

Comment: Wherever you initiate vue, search for the `new Vue` in your code. Depending on whether you are using Vuex 3 or 4, you then pass the store as an option according to method in the docs. https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store:~:text=new%20Vue(%7B%0A%20%20el%3A%20%27%23app%27%2C%0A%20%20store%3A%20store%2C%0A%7D)